# svn reintegrate pattern of deleting and recreating branches

Tags: svn, merge, branching-and-merging

The recommended practice of using `--reintegrate` is generally understood by me. However, the practice of reintegration recommends that the branch be deleted, and if needed for maintenance or warranty development, the branch should be "recreated."

However, most examples show the recreation of the reintegrated and deleted branch under a new name.

What harm is there if the branch is deleted after reintegration, then recreated in place under the same name? (Let's say our build engineers sorta require the name to remain static, and the branch must retain its name.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a any harm possible. Having the same name saves troubles on the configuration side of things.

You might want to read this for an alternative to deleting: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.reintegratetwice